# Checking whether this sequence is convergent or divergent

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

**Q:** Check if the following series is convergent or divergent and if convergent, find the limit:

$$\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{3}x^\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}x^\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}x^\frac{1}{4}+ \ldots}{1+x+x^\frac{1}{2}+x^\frac{1}{3}+x^\frac{1}{4}+ \ldots}$$

**My Attempt:** I have used D'Alembert's Ratio Test, Cauchy's Root Test but to no help since all give the inconclusive result. I tried to use Comparison Test but could not find a proper sequence to compare.

I don't know if we can make some conclusion by proving the convergence or divergence of the numerator and denominators separately.

Any form of help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it about the existence of the limit of $$\frac{1 + \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{k+1}x^{1/k}}{1 + \sum_{k = 1}^n x^{1/k}},$$ or something else?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yeah that's my question in a closed form.

Comment: The whole idea is to notice that regardless of whether $|x|>1$ or $|x|<1,$ we have $\sqrt[n]{|x|}\to1$ as $n\to\infty.$ So this is roughly like being asked to evaluate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{H_n}n,$ which is obviously $0.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the $x^{1/k}$ defined, one must suppose that $x\geq 0$. If $x=0$, the result is easy; suppose $x>0$. Note that $x^{1/k}\to 1$ as $k\to +\infty$, so the numerator and denominator are divergent series. Now, if you want to study $$v_n=\frac{1+\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^{1/k}}{k+1}}{1+\sum_{k=1}^n x^{1/k}}$$ then put $u_0=1$, $u_k=x^{1/k}$ for $k\geq 1$, and $a_k=\frac{1}{k+1}$. You have $$v_n=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^n a_k u_k}{\sum_{k=0}^n u_k}$$
and as $u_k>0$, $\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n u_k \to +\infty$ and  $a_k\to 0$, by Cesaro's Theorem, you have $v_n\to 0$.

Comment: You have used the notations $u_k$ and $u_n$ together at the same time to mean different things. Can you edit it? Its quite confusing.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Thank you very much, I have edited.